# Get the Windows Scheduler's Location Or Code?

Tags: windows-services, windows-task-scheduler

Today i got a task to find the scheduler that is running once in a month, actually I have to change its running time period to once a week.

I have searched for it in the Windows scheduled tasks, but i didn't find it. It is sending a mail containing a link. Now i am not confused about this where else can i find it. As the place i know where the scheduler can be, has already been checked by me. Can someone suggest me where else can i search for this scheduler?

As per the previous developer's comment "It is a normal Windows method of scheduling tasks"

**UPDATE**

Actually the task is running after a month periodically.
As per my knowledge it could be a "Windows Task Schedule" or "Windows Service" created by the old developer. Now as the previous developer is not available and i do not have any documentation.. i need to change the time period from month to weakly. I have checked in the "Task Schedules" on the server and checked the services running ob the server and was unable to find the "Scheduler". now i have two questions:

1. is there any other approach by using that i can schedule an automated email periodically.
2. any idea to find this.

Comment: Please clarify. Are you talking about Windows Scheduler (part of the OS that is scheduling threads to CPUs) or are you talking about Windows Task Scheduler Service (running programs at a given time/Event)? What do you have, what do you want, what does/does not work?

Comment: Are you sure it is set up as a scheduled task? Could it be a regular Windows service with its own internal timer?

Comment: @MoonSire please see the updated question